Interfacing ntripclient ROS2 RTCM error messages with ZEDF9P
RTCM error messages fed to the ZEDF9P rover does not have impact on GPS receiver accuracy.
The RTCM messages fed to the ZEDF9P do not seem to have any impact on the accuracy of the NMEA messages.
We are trying to interface ROS2 ntripclient RTCM error messages with our ZEDF9P GPS module configured as a Rover:
The RTCM error messages are in following format:
header:
  stamp:
    sec: 1716298564
    nanosec: 352618551
  frame_id: odom
data:
- 211
- 0
- 19
- 62
- 208
- 0
- 3
- 136
- 164
- 96
- 85
- 252
- 191
- 11
- 95
- 2
- 88
- 11
- 255
- 176
- 0
- 67
- 144
- 238
- 83
---

As per our understanding "data" contains the RTCM messages.
We are using below code to feed RTCM messages and read NMEA messages via the ZEDF9P USB interface (configured to handle appropriates messages):
#include <rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp>
#include <mavros_msgs/msg/rtcm.hpp>
#include <libserial/SerialPort.h>
#include <libserial/SerialPortConstants.h>


class SerialTalkerNode : public rclcpp::Node
{
public:
  SerialTalkerNode(const std::string& node_name, const std::string& port, const int baudrate)
  : Node(node_name), port_(port), baudrate_(baudrate)
  {
    // Create subscriber
    //publisher_ = this->create_publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>("topic", 10);
      timer_ = this->create_wall_timer(std::chrono::milliseconds(100), std::bind(&SerialTalkerNode::publishCommand, this));
      subscription_ = create_subscription<mavros_msgs::msg::RTCM>(
      "/ntrip_client/rtcm", // Replace with your topic name
      10,
      std::bind(&SerialTalkerNode::topicCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1));
      //std::string fileName = "/dev/pts/11";
      std::string fileName = "/dev/ttyACM1";
      serial_.Open(fileName);
      
    // Open serial port
    /*
    try {
      
      std::string fileName = "/dev/pts/7"; // Example file name
      std::ios_base::openmode mode = std::ios_base::in | std::ios_base::out; // Example open mode      
      serial_.Open(fileName, mode);
    } catch (const serial::IOException& e) {
      RCLCPP_ERROR(this->get_logger(), "Failed to open serial port: %s", e.what());
      rclcpp::shutdown();
    }
    */
    
  }

private:
  rclcpp::Subscription<mavros_msgs::msg::RTCM>::SharedPtr subscription_;
  //rclcpp::Publisher<std_msgs::msg::String>::SharedPtr publisher_;

  LibSerial::SerialPort serial_;
  std::string port_;
  int baudrate_;
  rclcpp::TimerBase::SharedPtr timer_;
  void topicCallback(const mavros_msgs::msg::RTCM::SharedPtr  msg)
  { 
    
    for(int i=0;i<sizeof(msg->data);i++)
    {      
      
      serial_.WriteByte(msg->data[i]);
    }  
  }

  void publishCommand() {

      LibSerial::DataBuffer NMEA_Buff;
      serial_.Read(NMEA_Buff,2000,0);
      std::cout<<NMEA_Buff.size()<<"\n";
      for(unsigned char dat : NMEA_Buff)
      {
        if(dat=='$')
        {
          std::cout<<"\n";
        }
        else
        std::cout<<dat;
      }
  }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  rclcpp::init(argc, argv);
  auto node = std::make_shared<SerialTalkerNode>("serial_talker", "/dev/ttyUSB0", 115200); // Replace with your settings
  rclcpp::spin(node);
  rclcpp::shutdown();
  return 0;
}

The error messages does not seem to have any impact on accuracy.
